# VB.net server not accessible from outside even when using a wildcard

Tags: vb.net, server

I have set up a VB.NET server but it only responds to requests from it's own host. If I try to send a request from a different computer (on the same network) it does not respond to the request, it just times out. My application basically listens for a request on port `1212` then takes a screenshot and sends the response back.

I tried using both `http://*:1212/` and `http://+:1212/` but it only works if I issue the request from the computer where the server is hosted.

**From the host, this works**
`http://192.168.1.150:1212/`

**From another computer on the network, this does not work**
`http://192.168.1.150:1212/` *(the request times out)*

**Here is my application**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private t As New Thread(AddressOf IncomingMessage)
    Private Const bufferSize As Integer = 1024 * 512
    Dim prefixes(0), Port, UserIP, UserIPPort As String
    Dim isWorking As Boolean = False


    ' From1_Load()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        prefixes(0) = "http://*:1212/"

        With t
            If (.ThreadState And ThreadState.Unstarted) <> 0 Then
                .IsBackground = True
                .Start()
            End If
        End With
    End Sub


    ' IncomingMessage()
    Private Sub IncomingMessage()
    Bgn:
        If prefixes(0) Is Nothing OrElse prefixes(0).Length = 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("prefixes")
        End If

        Dim listener As HttpListener = New HttpListener()

        For Each s As String In prefixes
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s)
        Next

        Try
            listener.Start()

            Dim numRequestsToBeHandled As Integer = 10

            For i As Integer = 0 To numRequestsToBeHandled
                Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = Nothing
                Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()
                Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
                Dim URLRequestClient As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

                MessageBox.Show(URLRequestClient)

                Dim bmp As Bitmap = ScreenCap()
                bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\screenshot.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                bmp.Dispose()

                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

                Dim buffer = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}

                Using fs = File.OpenRead(Application.StartupPath & "\screenshot.jpg")
                    context.Response.ContentLength64 = fs.Length

                    Dim read As Integer

                    While (InlineAssignHelper(read, fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0
                        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                    End While
                End Using

                context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
            Next
        GoTo Bgn
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was an issue with the Firewall on my Windows 10 laptop where I was running the server. I turned off firewall for private and public networks and it worked. I suppose a better solution would be to add my application to the `allowed list` of applications to go through the firewall. *(But for some reason that didn't work, I had to turn off Firewall completely)*